# Detect trackpad edge gesture

Tags: swift, macos

I have a menu bar app which listens in the background for certain events. I already managed to hook into the keyboard and do stuff when the user enters a certain combination. Now I also wanted to hook into the trackpad and allow the user to do some actions when he swipes his trackpad.

The gesture I am after for is swiping from either side of the trackpad (outside to inside). I have found several apps which already hook into this behavior, latest example I found is contexts https://contexts.co/ .

I already tried with `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`, but when I try to read the touches from the callback the app crashes.

The behavior I am looking for is this:

[image: Trackpad gesture].